# How to use Logger in a gradle buildSrc class?

Tags: gradle

So, when I do the naive thing and just use:

```
logger.info("something")
```

I get:

```
<myfile>.groovy: 52: Apparent variable 'logger' was found in a
static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class.
Possible causes:
You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an
instance variable from a static context.
You misspelled a classname or statically imported field.
Please check the spelling.
You attempted to use a method 'logger' but left out brackets
in a place not allowed by the grammar.
   @ line 52, column 9.
       logger?.info("Resolving ${projectPath} to ${version}")
```

I tried many variants, like setting up a class variable in a constructor:

```
static private log = Logging.getLogger(MyClass)
```

This fails with Logging being found in a static scope...

What is the magic here?

Comment: It appears as if gradle's logging only makes sense within a project or a task context.

Comment: Yes, definitely. You need to get `project` instance to use logger. So implement `Plugin` or extend `DefaultTask`.

Answer (score 2):

[Gradle User Guide, chapter 18](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/logging.html) says you can just use [SLF4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) in your buildSrc. I had luck with the @Slf4j annotation on the class. For example:

```
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j

@Slf4j
class YourClass {
      def logIt(){
          log.info 'This is logged in Gradle'
      }
}
```